# Soft Question: What does periodic cyclic theory measure?

Tags: soft-question, homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology, cyclic-homology

**Ex1)** The cyclic homology of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ and that of the algebra of functions on the sphere $S^2$ have the same periodic cyclic homology.  Clearly, however, these objects are topologically very different (thinking of the former as the affine scheme $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$).
So what exactly does this periodic (co)homology theory measure/ describe?

**Ex2)** Or consider the cyclic homology of the algebras of smooth functions on $\mathbb{C}P^n$, $\coprod_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{C}^i$ and $\coprod_{i = 1}^n S^i$.  These are all very different spaces, yet they still have the same periodic cyclic homology!

(The calculation is straightforward using the Periodic to DeRham degeneration, that is: $HP^*(A)\cong \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} H_{\text{dR}}^{2n + *}(M)$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold and $A$ is its algebra of smooth functions).

**Observation/Note:**  I know in part that cyclic homology was introduced by Tsygan as a sort of "non-commutative de Rham" cohomology, making use of its relationship to the Hochschild homology (which acts as non-commutative differential forms).  However, this so called "stabilized version" seems to be innacurate, at least topologically.  Moreover, if it is supposed to generalise the de Rham theory, why is it viewed as more favorable than Karoubi's non-commutative de Rham cohomology, which actually degenerates to the ususal algebraic de Rham complex in the case of a commutative unital associative algebra?

**Accuracy gained from non-periodicity?** 
Likewise, is it possible for the coordinate rings (or algebra of smooth functions of a compact manifold) to correspond to homotopic spaces and yet have different periodic cyclic homologies?  Or, more generally, to have different cyclic homologies?

(**As a general note**: cyclic homology (as far as I know) is only invariant under differential homotopy, if the underlying algebra is formally smooth, so I don't see why this should be true in general.)

Comment: Not so different: $S^2$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so the reduced homology of the former is the Borel-Moore homology of the latter. I don't know if this is at all relevant to periodic cyclic homology though.

Comment: I put up anoth example linking the periodic theory of $CP^n$ to that of a disjoint union of n-spheres, or of n-disjoint points, certainly these re wilsedly differnet beasts.

Comment: If you have two compact manifolds which are homotopy equivalent, the periodic cyclic homology of the corresponding algebras of smooth functions is going to be the same. Cyclic homology is not homotopy invariant.